# extract date-month-year from retrieved date

Tags: java, android, date

i am getting the system current date and trying to display it in a textview.

after trying the below code

```
private OnClickListener listener1 = new OnClickListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        long dtMili = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Date dt = new Date(dtMili);
        gett.setText(dt.toString());
        
    }
};
```

**what i get is**

[image]

but i only want something like `15/7/2013`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String date = sdf.format(dt);
```

Also see [Customizing Formats](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    long dtMili = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Date dt = new Date(dtMili);
    DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    gett.setText(df.format(dt).toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String dateStr=dateFormat.format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

I mostly prefer using JodaTime instead, for everything that has to handle Dates. In your case it looks as easy as this :

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(new Date());
String st = dt.toString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```